# Gradle Ear Plugin: Adding modules without version specifier

Tags: gradle, groovy, jboss, ear

I am trying to assemble an **ear** with Gradle, wich `application.xml` contains some non-ejb modules. The dependent project archives are generated with the `{basename}-{version}.{extension}` standard and thus look something like, e.g. `subproject-0.2.6.rar`. However, since some of these projects need to be marked as java or connector module, I have issues addressing the correct files.

This is what the build script looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy project(':EJB-Project')
    deploy project(':Commons')
    deploy project(':UpdateManager')

    earlib 'net.sf:jasperreports:unknown'
    earlib 'org.apache.axis:axis:1.4'
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = 'EnterpriseProject'

        module('Commons.jar', 'java')
        module('UpdateManager.rar', 'connector')
    }

    // Remove the version postfix from archived files
    rename(/(.*)-${version}(.)/, /$1$2/)
}
```

The `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` has the archives in the sub-deployment nodes declared without the version specifier, too.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
       ...
    <sub-deployment name="EJB-Project.jar">
        <dependencies />
        <exclusions />
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="Commons.jar">
        <dependencies />
        <exclusions />
    </sub-deployment>
        ...
```

The rename method in the ear task successfully renames the libraries from the `deploy` configuration, but Gradle adds the dependencies, which are not explicitly added via `module(String path, String identifier)` automatically with their original name as ejb module:

```
<module>
    <ejb>EJB-Project-4.5.2.jar</ejb>
</module>
```

I would love to solve this in a clean way - e.g., referencing the project itself in the module section, rather than specifying the file name (and its extension) and generating the deployment xml for JBoss, but I'm somehow stuck. I want all version strings to be removed, or keep all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved something similar like this in gradle 6.8:

I started from here:

```
plugins {
    id 'ear'
}

dependencies {
    deploy      'org.cpp.pp:dmReports:5.04.01-2'
    deploy      project(':reporting-transpoLib')
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        module('dmReports-5.04.01-2.jar', 'java')
        module("reporting-transpoLib-${project.version}.jar", 'java')
    }
}
```

which produced an ear containing jars with versions and deployment descriptor with versions.

But I had also a second war specifying in it's deployment descriptor a dependency to dmReports.

For each new version of dmReports, deployed via this ear, I had to updated also the war deployment descriptor (dependency section)- which was not ok.

I needed to remove the dmReports version from the ear and from war deployment descriptor.

So I changed to this the ear:

```
plugins {
    id 'ear'
}

configurations {
    dmReports
    reportingTranspoLib
}

dependencies {
    dmReports          'org.cpp.pp:dmReports:5.04.01-2'
    reportingTranspoLib project(':reporting-transpoLib')
}

// copyToLib task copies the dependencies and rename them (remove version) in a separate 
// folder: ${buildDir}/lib. This folder will be used as input for deploy configuration

task copyToLib {
    dependsOn(':reporting-transpoLib:build')

    doFirst {
        def  configNames = [ 'dmReports', 'reportingTranspoLib']
        configNames.each { configName ->
            configurations.getByName(configName).resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
                project.copy {
                    from artifact.file
                    into "${buildDir}/lib"
                    rename { "${artifact.name}.${artifact.extension}" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the output of copyToLib task (folder ${buildDir/lib}) is taken and used by configuration deploy

dependencies {
    deploy files("${buildDir}/lib")
}


ear {
    dependsOn(copyToLib)
//    from(copyToLib)
    deploymentDescriptor {
        module('dmReports.jar', 'java')
        module("reporting-transpoLib.jar", 'java')
    }
}
```

So I obtained an ear containing jars without versions and deployment descriptor without versions.
Was very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin, that generates the JBoss Deployment Structure [on GitHub](https://github.com/mamohr/jboss-deployment-structure).
Since I found no clean way of solving this somehow else, I just implemented the features I was missing on the plugin and the owner merged them.